# Replace the "AND" between authors' names in citations and references with its equivalent in another language, e.g., Spanish

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, babel, chicago-style

I have been using the `achicago` package and the `babel` package for spanish language. When I employ the two, references with multiple authors are shown in the citations like (Mukange **and** Manamela) but it should (Mukange **y** Manamela) with a "Y", because the thesis is in Spanish. The same happens when the authors are listed in the bibliography.

Is there a way to change the "and" when authors are listed in a citation and in the bibliography for its equivalent in other languages?

Comment: Is biblatex on option for you? It's fully localised and does this sort of thing well.

Answer (score 3):

Some BibTeX styles use `\biband`, or similar, instead of "and". You can have a look into the `.bbl` file to see if this is the case, and then renew that command to "y" in the main document.

If, instead, the BibTeX style writes a literal "and" in the `.bbl`, you are out of luck. In this case I would recommend you to create a customized BibTeX style using `custom-bib`. To do so, run the command:

```bsh
$ tex makebst
```

and then answer a lot of questions about how do you want your bibliography. Give the answers that are consistent with the Chicago style you used to use. When asked about the "and", choose the `\biband` option. After all questions have been answered, you'll get a `.bst` file, which is the custom style you should use (`\bibliographystyle`).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `achicago.bst` is not fully internationalized, so `babel` will be of no help here.

You can fix this by hand, however: make a copy of `achicago.bst`, say `myachicago.bst`, and place it somewhere where `bibtex` will find it, e.g., in the directory of your document. Open the new file with an editor, and replace all occurences of `" and "` with `" y "` (should be three times, in lines 1318, 1357, 1398). Save the file, and use `myachicago` as your `bibtex` style from now on, i.e., with `\bibliographystyle{myachicago}`.

While you are at it, you might customize other hard coded strings. I spotted `"others"`, `",~eds."` (for editors), `",~ed."`, `"By"`, `"Illustrated by "`, `"as "`, `"pp."` (for pages), and some more.

Comment: While performing the edits of the renamed `.bst` file, you may want to recommend changing all instances of `"others"` to "`otros`" (or whatever suits the OP's needs). That way, instances of "and others" will be typeset as "y otros"...