# Spanish references and bibliography

Tags: bibtex, naming

I'm using the following commands for my bibliographical stile in TexMaker:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{econometrica}
\bibliography{<referencias>}
```

I'd like to know How to modify LaTeX/MikteX so the references in the text and also the bibliography appear like

> xxx y xxx (1990)

instead of

> xxx and xxx (1990)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Very closely related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1279/15925

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the econometrica bibliography style does not support internationalization using babel.

I think that it should be enough to replace `" and "` by `" y "` in line 351, 382 and 995 of the `econometrica.bst` file, since it looks like they are the only occurrence of the keyword. There are other strings that you may also want to change like "others".

For a more detailed answer to a similar problem see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94929/10303).