# Bibliography sorting issue

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sorting

I would like my bibliography sorted by author. I don't know why it is not working in my current document. Can you help me? I am new in LaTeX. Thanks, Pablo.

```
documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authoryear, round, sort]{natbib} 


\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={black}}
\   usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}


\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\renewcommand\thefigure{%
   \ifnum\value{subsection}=0{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}%
   \else{\thesubsection.\arabic{figure}}\fi}

  \usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\title{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\author{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}

\date{\vspace{-5ex}}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\cite{Chung16}
\citep{Devereux15}

\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

Examples of biblio entries:

```
@Article{Chung16,
  author={Chung, Wanyu},
  title={\textbf{Imported inputs and invoicing currency choice: Theory and         evidence from UK transaction data}},
  journal={Journal of International Economics},
  year=2016,
  volume={99},
  number={C},
  pages={237-250},
  url={https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/inecon/v99y2016icp237-250.html}
}

@techreport{Devereux15,
 title = {\textbf{Exchange Rate Pass-Through, Currency of Invoicing and     Market Share}},
 author = "Michael B. Devereux and Ben Tomlin and Wei Dong",
 institution = "National Bureau of Economic Research",
 type = "Working Paper",
 series = "Working Paper Series",
 number = "21413",
 year = "2015",
 month = "July",
 URL = "http://www.nber.org/papers/w21413",
}
```

Comment: Which sorting have you defined in `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}`?

Comment: Assuming `myplainnat` has the same sorting setup as `plainnat`, your code will deliver a formatted bibliography with entries sorted by the surnames of the respective first-named authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed plainnat since I wanted to change "and" for "y" (spanish reference) like was suggested here:

[Replace the "AND" between authors' names in citations and references with its equivalent in another language, e.g., Spanish](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/replace-the-and-between-authors-names-in-citations-and-references-with-its-eq)

```
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
```

Apparently i did not replace all the "and" in the .bst document. Now I replaced all and it is working fine.

It is fixed!